# How to use df.saveToPhoenix() to save DataFrame to phoenix table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, bigdata, apache-phoenix

After looking for the right way to save a DataFrame to Phoenix for a long time, I noticed that the `df.save()` method is actually provided by `DataFrame.class` in Spark1.x.

When I use:

```
df.saveToPhoenix(
      store_table,
      zkUrl = Some(hconnection)
)
```

I got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.spark.package$.toDataFrameFunctions(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/phoenix/spark/DataFrameFunctions;
    at com.***.data.process.phoenix.PhoenixToHBase$.main(PhoenixToHBase.scala:63)
    at com.***.data.process.phoenix.PhoenixToHBase.main(PhoenixToHBase.scala)
```

I think there maybe some conflicts between those jars or maybe I missed some jars.

I have written those dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
   <artifactId>phoenix-spark</artifactId>
   <version>4.14.0-cdh5.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
   <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.14.0-cdh5.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and even added `phoenix-4.14.0-cdh5.14.2-client.jar` from local disk according to [phoenix_spark.html-->Spark setup](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html).
If you know how to solve this problem , please give me some advices or your pom.xml.

Comment: What is your Spark version? According to the link you included phoenix 4.10 and later are compatible with spark 2.x.

Comment: I changed the version of those jars and finally solve the problem . change " 4.14.0-cdh5.12.2 "  to " 4.14.0-HBase-1.2 "  and  the version of Spark is " 2.3.0 "